# Changing model field value to True after expiration time

Tags: python, django

I am in the process of creating a simple car rental project in Django.

I have a view in which the user must enter the value for how many days he wants to rent a car and press the "Rent" button. In this situation the "is_car_available" field of the "Car" model gets False value and it is not possible to rent.

```py
@login_required
def rent(request, pk):
    car_to_rent = Car.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RentingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            days = form.cleaned_data['days']
            total_price = car_to_rent.car_price * days
            reservation = Reservation.objects.create(how_many_days=days, car=car_to_rent, booker=request.user, total_price=total_price)
            car_to_rent.is_car_availible = False
            car_to_rent.save()


        content_for_frontend = {
            'car_to_rent': car_to_rent,
            'form': form,
        }

        return render(request, 'rental/rent.html', content_for_frontend)

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

The Reservation model has the "expiration_date" method, which is calculated after adding the rental date to the number of days.
I would like to see "is_car_available" change to True at the end of the rental.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

It's quite simple. All you need is to prepare script to change model field to True and put this script to CRON table on your server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

**Example bash file in CRON Table**

```
#!/bin/bash 

source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate
cd /path/to/your/project/folder
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settingsFile
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
python manage.py shell < cron.py
```

**Example cron.py**

```
import os
import sys
import django
django.setup()
import pytz, time
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Q
form appName.models import modelName

items = modelName.objects.filter(
    Q(is_car_availiable=False),
    Q(reserved_untill__lte=timezone.now())
    )
update_data = {
    "is_car_acailiable": True,
    "reserved_untill": None
}
items.update(**update_data)
```

Comment: this will work in my virtual environment, and what about others?

Comment: and could you explain it like for an idiot because I still don't get it.

Comment: OK first of all you have to find out how to set cron job at your hosting provider. If you use SSH you can use: crontab -l (listing your cron jobs), crontab -e (edit), crontab -r (remove). It should be described ad your hosting provider documentation.